# How to execute filter and includes

Tags: javascript

Trying to loop through second array to see if the first array have a match, where there is match then the index of the second array(or a new array) will contain the number of each time to element was found and it will display it in a new array:

```
function getOccur(ar1, ar2){
  let ar = [];
  return ar2.filter((el,i)=>ar2.includes((el)=>{
    ar[i]+= 1;
  }));
  return ar;
}
getOccur(
  ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pp', 'pear', 'orange'],
  ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana']
);
```

The output I want is:

```
[2, 2, 1, 0]
```

That is, `apple` occurs 2 times, `orange` occurs 2 times, `pear` occurs 1 time and `banana` occurs 0 times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about looping the 2nd array, and count how many times each item is present in the first array using filter? In that way, you can remove the `includes` and code is much easier to understand.

```js
function getOccur(arr1, arr2) {
  let finalArr = [];
  arr2.forEach((a) => {
    finalArr.push(arr1.filter(item => item === a).length);
  });
  return finalArr;
}

const arr1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pp', 'pear', 'orange'];
const arr2 = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana'];

console.log(getOccur(arr1, arr2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to count up the number of occurances - `includes` will only give you `true` or `false`, and `filter` will only give you a filtered version of the original array. Neither of those are all that appropriate for this situation - I'd use `reduce` instead, for an `O(n)` solution:

```js
const getOccur = (ar1, ar2) => Object.values(
  ar1.reduce(
    (a, item) => {
      if (item in a) a[item]++;
      return a;
    },
    ar2.reduce((a, prop) => {
      a[prop] = 0;
      return a;
    }, {})
  )
);

console.log(
  getOccur(
    ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pp', 'pear', 'orange'],
    ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana']
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using map and forEach

```
function getOccur(ar1, ar2) {
    const result = ar2.map(fruit => {
        let foundCount = 0;
        ar1.forEach((element) => { foundCount += (element === fruit ? 1 : 0) })
        return foundCount
    })
    return result
  }
  console.log(getOccur(['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pp', 'pear', 'orange'], ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Array filter may not fulfill what you want.

Just do with two `forEach` that would work fine.

```js
function getOccur(ar1, ar2) {
    let ar = [];
    let index = 0;
    ar2.forEach(
        (el) => {
            ar.push(0);
            ar1.forEach(
                (el2) => {
                    if (el == el2) ar[index] += 1;
                }
            );
            index++;
        }
    );
    return ar;
}
console.log(
getOccur(
    ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pp', 'pear', 'orange'], ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana']
));
```